# Blazor Component - On change localization

Tags: blazor

I created the resource file for localization. while page loading, it set the current culture info but changing the language from drop down list, it's not changing.

Here is my code,

**Localization.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Localization> localizer

<h3>@localizer["Title"]</h3>

@localizer["Content"]

<select @onchange="OnSelected">
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="de">German</option>
</select>

@code {
   private void OnSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      // Code
    
   }
}
```

What needs to write in OnSelected event for changing selected language?

Thanks in advance.

**MainLayout.razor:**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="sidebar">
   <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
   <div class="top-row px-4">
      <select @onchange="OnSelected">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
      </select>
   </div>
 <div class="content px-4">
    @Body
 </div>
</div>

@code {
  private void OnSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
  {
      var selectedCulture = e.Value.ToString();
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = 
          CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
            .First(c => c.Name == selectedCulture);
   }
}
```

**Localization.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject IStringLocalizer<Localization> localizer

<h3>@localizer["Title"]</h3>
@localizer["Content"]
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        
        services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("de") };
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("de");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
        app.UseRouting();

        app.ApplicationServices
            .UseBootstrapProviders()
            .UseFontAwesomeIcons();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the language of your browser to load the different resources. I have a repo here.   https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorLocalisation

Comment: I need to call the resource file based on dropdown selection. Please provide the code for OnSelected event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the current culture :

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Localization> localizer

<h3>@localizer["Title"]</h3>

@localizer["Content"]

<select @onchange="OnSelected">
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="de">German</option>
</select>

@code {
   private void OnSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      // Code
      var selectedCulture = e.Value.ToString();
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                .First(c => c.Name == selectedCulture);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working fine blazor component page and Changed to CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture. Suppose if i use the same code in MainLayout.razor page, on selection event, it's not changing the text based on selected language in other pages. Please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to refresh the page with a call to StateHasChanged

Comment: StateHasChanged also used in MainLayout.razor component but its not working.

Comment: What if you call localizer.GetAllStrings() ?

Comment: Getting existing resource details not latest resource details

Comment: How do you declare `IStringLocalizer<Localization>` in your DI ?

Comment: I have added the code of MainLayout.razor and Localization.razor page in question. Please refer the same.

Comment: Post your program.cs

Comment: Included program.cs and startup.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223106/discussion-between-gunasekaran-and-agua-from-mars).

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem. Have you been able to resolve it and if yes, what is the solution?